# Android simulators in Xamarin (Visual Studio) wont start in ASUS UX410U Notebook - Windows 10

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It's been 3 days that I am trying to get Xamarin in Visual Studio working, unfortunately with no success. The errors that I get when I am trying to start android simulators are the following:

- Missing config.ini file in the AVD data folder
  or Device System image is incomplete and cannot be launched. Do you want us to reinstall the image?
  [Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGlSk.jpg)
  [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9IQU.jpg)

Pressing OK wont fix the problem.

I have tried many times to reinstall xamarin deleting all xamarin folders and files I could find in my filesystem and repairing Visual Studio but the same problems pop up every time.

I really don't know what else to do since I am new to Xamarin.

Furthermore, in the avd folder in a simulator folder (e.g. pixel_2_oreo_8_1__api_27.avd) there are only 3 files (config, sdcard, userdata) when in another pc that xamarin works fine there are a lot more (files and folders).
[Simulator folder in pc that works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKRju.jpg)
[Simulator folder in pc with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doiv7.jpg)

I really could use any help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You said that you also have error when connecting to your mobile to run xamarin app? Visual Studio can detect your device or not?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem was that the avd folder and the debug.keystore of the Mono Android were placed within my windows user folder which was in greek characters creating problems reading the paths. Changing my windows user folder to english characters fixed the problem. Although i strongly recommend to be very careful or avoid doing something like that because there is great possibility to have problems with the windows and other apps afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new emulator selecting another device, else try creating emulator via `Android Studio`. But remember to keep the path same for jdk & sdk of Android Studio & visual studio.

1. There might be the case of internet as well, the OS image you trying to download couldn't get downloaded completely cuz of some issues in network connection.

Comment: I have created other emulator selecting another device. Unfortunately, i dont have the Android Studio installed and my internet connection is stable.

Comment: if i try to run the app even though emulator doesnt start i get this message:PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
Emulator pixel_2_nougat_7_0_-_api_24 cannot be started.

Comment: `Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` thats the error if your OS image is not getting downloaded properly  maybe cuz the OS image & the device you selecting are not having a proper match or the path to SDK is invalid.

Comment: The paths for the java development kit and android sdk location looks fine. I tried to reinstall everything yesterday but the problem wasnt fixed.

Comment: I have also tried to connect my mobile to run from there to see if it works but build fails with the following messages:2>C:\Users\Δημητρης\source\repos\App10\App10\App10.Android\obj\Debug\90\lp\33\jl\res : error APT2097: failed to open directory: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
2>C:\Users\Δημητρης\source\repos\App10\App10\App10.Android\obj\Debug\90\lp\34\jl\res : error APT2097: failed to open directory: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).

Comment: Do you think reinstalling visual studio may fix the problem?

Comment: you can try that...hope that might fix your issue